# JQuery Datepicker returned Date object type

Tags: jquery, datepicker

What's the object type returned by Datepicker?
Supposing I have the following:

```
$("#txtbox").datepicker({
   onClose: function(date){
          //something
       }
});
```

What is `date`? I'm interested in reading the date object from another Datepicker for comparison, something like:

```
   function(date){
       oDate = $("#oDP").datepicker("getDate");
       if(oDate == date)
          //do one
       else if(oDate > date)
          //do two
   }
```

However, this kind of comparison is not working. I'm guessing there is some sort of comparison method for Date object, but I don't know. I also tried comparing the String representation of the dates like `oDate.toString() > date.toString()` to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just downloaded the source from [here](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js) and noticed (ex line 600) the author is using .getTime() to compare dates, have you tried that?

```
if (oDate.getTime() > date.getTime()) {
    ...
}
```

Also this is tangential but you mention you tried oDate.toString() while I noticed in the [examples](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html) the author is using .asString()

Comment: Hi @Pat your link is now a 404 page.

Comment: Two years later the web has changed :-) I think I managed to track the new link and fixed it thanks for the heads up ...

Answer (score 5):

A `Date` object is returned by the `datePicker`.

Your method for comparing dates is valid - from [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp):

```
var myDate=new Date();
myDate.setFullYear(2010,0,14);
var today = new Date();

if (myDate>today)
{
    alert("Today is before 14th January 2010");
}
```

Are you getting a value in `oDate` from this line?

```
oDate = $("#oDP").datepicker("getDate");
```

Your comparison method seems valid - so I'm wondering if `datePicker` is successfully pulling a value from `#oDP`?

**Edit** - `oDate` confirmed to contain a valid date. This may be a very silly question, but have you confirmed that `date` contains a valid date? I'm wondering if there may be some issue with naming it the same as the keyword `Date` ([Javascript keywords and reserved words](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)). Perhaps try renaming it to `tDate` or the like in your function to be doubly-clear this isn't causing your problems.

Comment: My $("#oDP") is returning a Date. I have a alert(oDate) to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to compare dates, it works:
$("#datepickerfrom").datepicker("getDate") < $("#datepickerto").datepicker("getDate")

Answer (score -2):

> What is date?

it's the $("#txtbox") object

Comment: The JQuery documentation says that date is the Date object value of the Datepicker instance that is attached to the txtbox element. I have printed the value of date (alert(date)) and it is in fact a Date object.