# JQuery datepicker onSelect calling Url.Acion

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

again bit new to Jquery!

Have the following script and action. The action is being called ok but the id is always empty.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            dateformat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function(date, inst) {
                $('#diary img').attr(
                    'src', 
                    '<%= Url.Action("Image") %>?id=' + date.toString());
            }
        });
    });        
</script>

public ActionResult Image(string id)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine and it should work (other than the trailing comma that you should remove after the closing `}` of the `onSelect` method and the `dateformat` property which should be `dateFormat`). Can you see the request in the Net tab of FireBug? How does the requested url look like?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. Yes can see the request in firebug I'm getting http://localhost:1842/Diary/Image?id=03/25/2011 - still empty though!

Answer (score 0):

Use .asString() instead. That's the method the author of datePicker uses. credits to: [JQuery Datepicker returned Date object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154427/jquery-datepicker-returned-date-object-type/234380#234380)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working by playing around a bit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({                
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function() {
            var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');                
            $('#diary img').attr(
                    'src',
                    '<%= Url.Action("Image") %>/' + date.val().toString());
            }                               
        });
    });        
</script>
```