# Get the date selected in a DatePicker within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i'd like to get the date the user has selected in a JS function.

i already tried to use this :

> ```
> var test = $("#datepicker").datepicker( 'getDate' );
> ```

with an alert but it displays [object object] instead of the date.
this really drives me crazy.
Does anyone know ?
thanks in advance

Comment: what date picker you are using care to provide the name/link to plugin?

Comment: you're probably dealing with a true Date object. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: this also may help-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154427/jquery-datepicker-returned-date-object-type

Answer (score 3):

I've just had a look at a datepicker i have, and the 'getDate' function returns an object of what appears to be the current date:

```
Date {Fri Jan 27 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)}
```

You may wish to try:

```
var test = $("#datepicker").val();
```

This will simply get the value from the text box once the value has been changed by the date picker. Which returned:

```
"01/31/2012"
```

Comment: Where i have written $("#datepicker"), this should be the input field itself. Is this the case?

Comment: I just have this :
        <asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" Width="120px" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: because i needed to have a webcontrol with runat="server", without it , datepicker no longer works...

Comment: From looking at the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650009/asp-net-and-jquery-ui-datepicker im guessing ASP generates it's own Ids. maybe try using a class instead..?

Comment: THANKS A LOT :
I USE THIS : var datepickerdebut = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl00_cphMain_cphMainMenu_datepicker").value;
AND IT WORKS PERFECTLY

Comment: Great stuff! Just as a side note, not sure how ASP works but might this ID change? Just something to bear in mind.